# ArrayList<int> vs ArrayList<int[]>?

Tags: java, generics, collections, reference, primitive-types

I am not able to figure out why ArrayList<**int**> is **not** **allowed** but ArrayList<**int[]**> is **allowed**.

I was under the impression that primitive data types are not allowed in Collections, so why is this legit?

Comment: Yeah, primitive data types are not allowed in Collections.

Comment: `int[]` is a reference type (i.e. you can assign an `int[]` to an `Object` variable).

Comment: `Object o = new int[10];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `array` in Java is an object. In Java, we can create arrays by using `new` operator and we know that every object is created using new operator. Hence we can say that `array` is also an object.

Collection only works on anything which is `Object`. `int` is the primitive datatype and `int[]` is the Object.

That is the reason `ArrayList<int>` is not allowed but `ArrayList<int[]>` is allowed.

Answer (score 6):

Generics only work for reference type (anything that is an **Object**).

Primitive `int` isn't a reference type.

`int[]` is, as *any* array is also an Object.

The proper way to deal with multiple int values is to either use **just** `int[]` (not putting them into lists), or to use `List<Integer>`. Which one to pick really depends on your exact use case.

Answer (score 2):

int is primitive.

int[] is object.

ArrayList with ANY_OBJECT is valid.

ArrayList with ANY_PRIMITIVE is not valid.

and as int[] is an object so ArrayList is possible but for int primitive ArrayList is INVALID.

Answer (score 0):

An array in Java is an object. In Java, we can create arrays by using new operator and we know that every object is created using **new** operator.

In Java, there is a class for every array type, so there’s a class for int[] and similarly for float, double etc.
The direct superclass of an array type is Object. Every array type implements the interfaces **Cloneable** and **java.io.Serializable**. All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array. This can be checked from below code :

```
public class Test { 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
    System.out.println(args instanceof Object); 
    int[] arr = new int[2]; 
    System.out.println(arr instanceof Object); 
 } 
}
```

Output : True
         True

The diamond operator used in ArrayList initialisation specifies a generic type. A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterised over types.

You can go through the source code for ArrayList here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

You can see that the type of elementData in parameterised constructor is Object. A primitive is a data type which is not an object :

`private transient Object[] elementData;`

So as **int** is primitive data type in java it cannot be used as Generic type where as **int[]** , that has direct superclass Object, can be.

You can read more about it here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Comment: "This can be checked from below code :" but `System.out.println(args instanceof Object[]);` would also be true, even though `Object[]` is not a superclass of `String[]`. (It is a super*type*, though).

Comment: @AndyTurner System.out.println(args.getClass().getSuperclass()); will output java.lang.Object. So class of a Sting[] is java.lang.String where as superclass is java.lang.Object which also makes it a supertype. However the vice versa is not true. A supertype may or may not be a superclass.